# Avoid blank pages in browser print

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a simple loop to retrieve posts (don't mind loop markup):

```
[begin loop]
  <h4 style="page-break-before: always;">[title]</h4><br>
  [content]
[end loop]
```

How can I avoid browser print function to display blank pages between contents, i.e. to throw page breaks that results in blank pages?

Like this:

```
Title1
Content

[page break]

Title2
Content

[page break]

(...)

TitleX
Content

[page break]

(blank page)

[page break]

TitleY
Content

[page break]

TitleZ
Content

[page break]
```